# How to wait until async calls are finished in a each loop before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I'm using **`cheerio`** and `axios` to get all links from a web page and making **GET** requests with `axios` with each link to check that it is a not broken link (*i.e.* **the status code is 200**).

Then, I want to put each broken link **URL** into an array.
I can't figure out how this works in term of `async` and `await`.

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

// returns an array of broken link urls
async function getAllBrokenLinks(url) {
    const res = await axios.get(url) // get webpage

    // if there was an error getting the data, return null
    if (!res || res.status != 200) { 
        return null;
    }

    let body = res.data.body.value; // get body html from res
    let results = [];

    $ = cheerio.load(body); // parse body html into cheerio
    let links = $('a'); // get all the links in the body

    $(links).each( (i, link) => {
        let linkText = $(link).text();
        let linkHref = $(link).attr('href');

        // check if the link is dead
        axios.get(linkHref)
        .then( (response) => {
            if (response.status != 200) {
                results.push(linkHref);
            }
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            results.push(linkHref);
        });
    })

    return results; // this returns an empty array instead of a populated array

}
```

I know that `axios.get()` is an async function but I'm not sure how I can wait for each GET request in the `each` loop to finish running before I return the populated array `results`.

EDIT: This is different from [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) because `$(links)` does not have a `.forEach` function.

EDIT: I tried this:

```
    const reqs = $(links).map( async (i, link) => {
        let linkText = $(link).text();
        let linkHref = $(link).attr('href');

        // check if the link is dead
       axios.get(linkHref)
       .then( (response) => {
           if (response.status != 200) {
               results.push(linkHref);
           }
       })
       .catch( (error) => {
           results.push(linkHref);
       });

       return axios.get(linkHref)
    })

    await Promise.all(reqs); // ERROR

    return results;
```

but it is now giving me this error:

```
(node:77480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

EDIT: I figured it out. Here is my code:

```
    // put each link text and href in the linkUrls array
    $(links).each( (i, link) => {
        linkUrls[String($(link).text())] = $(link).attr('href');
    })

    let results = {};
    results['title'] = pageTitle;

    let num = 0;

    for (const linkText in linkUrls) {

        const response = await axios.get(linkUrls[linkText])
        .then( (r) => {
            if (r.status != 200) {
                num += 1;
                results[ 'broken link ' + String(num)] = {
                    'text': linkText,
                    'url': linkUrls[linkText],
                    'status code': r.status
                }
            }

        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            num += 1;
            results[ 'broken link ' + String(num)] = {
                'text': linkText,
                'url': linkUrls[linkText],
                'status code': err.response.status
            }
        })
    }

    console.log('results: ', results);

    return results;
```

Comment: Try converting `.each` to a regular `for (const element of elements)` loop

Comment: If there is a `.map` function instead of `.each`?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 a `.map` function exists but I'm not sure how I'd use especially considering I want a `results` array that is likely not the same size as the `lists` array

Comment: if you do `const reqs = $(links).map(` and return the `axios.get(linkHref)` your last two lines can be `await Promise.all(reqs); return results;`

Comment: @vivianyoung i guess you'll need to use the `.toArray()` method to convert the Cheerio wrapper into something that can be consumed by `Promise.all`

Comment: @Bergi I figured it out and yes, you're correct. I retrieved each `linkText` and `linkHref ` from `$(links)` and put them into a new dictionary. From there, I used a for loop and I was able to populate and return the `results` array.

Comment: `$(links).each` and `[].forEach` are the same, at least in terms of the duplicate. They do have some differences, but the reason it doesn't work (and the solution) is identical.

Comment: @KevinB I see. That answer did help me in the end but there was an intermediate step that I had to resolve on my own before that answer proved useful. Thanks for your response.